# Finding the path of a folder with specific characters and latest date in python

Tags: python, date, format, directory

I have a `\\path\\to\\folder` which has many folders where `prefix` is `4MOX_` and `7MOX_` and the `suffix` is `Date in MM-DD-YYYY` like `03-08-2017`, `04-09-2016`. Sample set of the folders are given below. Can anyone help me to point out the folder with latest date and which has `4MOX_` in it for my further analysis.

Folders:

`4MOX_06-08-2016
4MOX_07-08-2017
4MOX_12-22-2017
6MOX_06-08-2017
6MOX_07-08-2017
6MOX_12-22-2017`

output:

I need to point out to folder `\\path\\to\\folder\\4MOX_12-22-2017`

Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: Why is this tagged `pandas`? Is the input stored in a dataframe?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the files in the folder are stored in a data frame

Comment: Also, please post your code. We usually like to see some proof that you've spent some time trying to solve the problem and aren't just pushing your work onto random strangers on the internet.

Comment: `all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]` I have taken this as source but it is creating by the last created date and not finding the specific strings.

Comment: Please [edit] it into the question. But I guess that means we don't have to use the dataframe as the input? The `pandas` tag looks a bit out of place here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey did remove pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

```
import os

your_path = '\\path\\to\\folder'

# list all files in the path
lst = os.listdir(your_path)

# find file names which starts with 4MOX
lst = [x for x in lst if x.startswith('4MOX')]

# sort the list to get the file with latest date (from comments)
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[-10:], '%m-%d-%Y'), reverse=True)

# create path of the file
os.path.join(your_path, lst[0])
```

Comment: @Manish - Aran was right I did try on other examples it worked but on the one which Aran provided it did not work

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks aran for bringing it up. I am fixing it.